# Clean up SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, self-join

```
SELECT pp.pat_key, MAX(pp.PROV_NPI) [Provider_ID], CONCAT(pp.LAST_NM,' ',pp.FIRST_NM) [Provider_Name]
  INTO pat_primary_provider
  FROM TRDW.dbo.PATIENT_PROVIDER pp
  WHERE IS_PCP=1
  AND pat_key IN (SELECT Consumer_ID FROM CareWire0521)
GROUP BY pp.PAT_KEY, pp.last_nm, pp.FIRST_NM;

SELECT ppp.*
  INTO ppp1
  FROM (SELECT PAT_KEY, MAX(provider_ID) AS maxprov FROM pat_primary_provider GROUP BY PAT_KEY) AS x 
  INNER JOIN pat_primary_provider AS ppp ON ppp.PAT_KEY = x.PAT_KEY AND ppp.Provider_ID = x.maxprov;
```

I need to get the results of `ppp1` only using one query (no `INTO` statements) in SQL Server. Please help.

Comment: Hint:  CTEs (using `WITH`)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the first query into a CTE (without the INTO clause). Then select from that.

```
;WITH pat_primary_provider AS
(
  -- The first query goes here
)
-- The second query goes here
```

But something like below might also return the PAT_KEY's with the maximum PROV_NPI:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   PAT_KEY, 
   MAX(PROV_NPI) AS [Max_Provider_ID], 
   CONCAT(LAST_NM,' ',FIRST_NM) AS [Patient_Provider_Full_Name]
  FROM TRDW.dbo.PATIENT_PROVIDER pp
  WHERE IS_PCP = 1
  AND PAT_KEY IN (SELECT Consumer_ID FROM CareWire0521)
GROUP BY PAT_KEY, LAST_NM, FIRST_NM
ORDER BY row_number() over (order by MAX(PROV_NPI) desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with just inserting the first query as subqueries into the second?

```
SELECT ppp.*
  FROM (SELECT PAT_KEY, MAX(provider_ID) AS maxprov FROM (SELECT pp.pat_key, MAX(pp.PROV_NPI) [Provider_ID], CONCAT(pp.LAST_NM,' ',pp.FIRST_NM) [Provider_Name]
  FROM TRDW.dbo.PATIENT_PROVIDER pp
  WHERE IS_PCP=1
  AND pat_key IN (SELECT Consumer_ID FROM CareWire0521)
GROUP BY pp.PAT_KEY, pp.last_nm, pp.FIRST_NM) GROUP BY PAT_KEY) AS x 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT pp.pat_key, MAX(pp.PROV_NPI) [Provider_ID], CONCAT(pp.LAST_NM,' ',pp.FIRST_NM) [Provider_Name]
  FROM TRDW.dbo.PATIENT_PROVIDER pp
  WHERE IS_PCP=1
  AND pat_key IN (SELECT Consumer_ID FROM CareWire0521)
GROUP BY pp.PAT_KEY, pp.last_nm, pp.FIRST_NM) AS ppp ON ppp.PAT_KEY = x.PAT_KEY AND ppp.Provider_ID = x.maxprov;
```